# Performance of Fully homomorphic encryption VS Paillier encryption in Practice

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption, complexity, performance

Consider two schemes both have computation complexity linear to the input size (i.e. number of inputs). One scheme is based on Paillier encryption and the other one is based on fully homomorphic encryption.

**Question 1**: In general, can we compare their performance (i.e. which one is faster)?

**Question 2**: In general, can we compare their ciphertext size( i.e. which one has smaller sized ciphertex)?

Comment: quick (and likely) guess: FHE is slower and gives larger ciphertexts.

Comment: @SEJPM Thank you. Is there any short justification for that?

Comment: This is the wrong comparison. You should compare Paillier to standard lattice-based encryption which is already additively homomorphic. My guess is that the lattice based encryption will win (and I know that this is Shai Halevi's claim as well).

Comment: @YehudaLindell Well, I am considering the scheme that is based on (multi-key) fully homomorphic encryption: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2214086

Comment: @YehudaLindell And I want to know whether Paillier encryption is faster than that.

Comment: But this makes no sense! Pailler is only additively homomorphic, so why are you comparing it to fully homomorphic?

Comment: @YehudaLindell Please imagine that I have a protocol for a particular function that satisfies all the properties that the protocol in the paper provides. Obviously except mine only supports a particular function whereas the protocol in the paper supports generic computation. Mine is based on Paillier encryption. So I want to say my protocol is faster in practice.

Comment: My guess is then like @SEJPM. I suggest that you look on ePrint for the most recent implementations of fully homomorphic encryption, and then you can compare.

Comment: Paillier encryption is faster one as fully homomorphic is very slow.
cipher text is more for Paillier encryption as we reduce cipher in FHE